# Count the elements in a list of a list(python)

Tags: python-3.x

[['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'e', 't','g']]
I want to count how many elements are in each list of the list.
so,[4,4,5].How can i do that in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `len` for each element on the given list:

```
l = [['s', 'a', 'b', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'd', 't'], ['s', 'c', 'e', 't','g']]
[len(x) for x in l] # [4, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize the len() function. It takes a list as a parameter and returns the elements count.
[python len function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_len.htm)